# How do I add a half-space between words using Word 365 and Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word, office365

How do I add a half-space between words using Word 365 and Windows 10?

Comment: Do you mean the web client or the Word 2016 application?

Comment: Have a look here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/half-space-semi-space-between-words/75bfe733-fe45-47c8-a935-88ffb8848098

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of settings that affect horizontal spacing
on the “Advanced” tab of the “Font” dialog. 
“Scale” is probably the best one for what you want. 
Select all the spaces between words
(you can handle the spaces between *sentences* differently if you want)

[image: text with spaces selected]

and click on the little [image: ribbon panel corner widget] symbol
in the lower right corner of the “Font” panel on the “Home” tab. 
This will open the “Font” dialog box. 
(On most desktop versions of Microsoft Word,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will also do this;
I don’t know about Word 365.) 
Go to the “Advanced” tab, click on the “Scale” dropdown, and select 150%.

[image: “Font” dialog box, “Advanced” tab]

This will make the spaces 50% wider than normal,
effectively adding a half space between words.

[image: text with spaces expanded]

Even though the “Scale” field has a dropdown,
you can type any number (up to 600) into the box.

You can get a similar effect with the “Spacing” field,
but that is measured in points rather than percent.

Selecting all the spaces like this is tedious. 
An easier method is to use Find and Replace to change the formatting:

[image: “Find and Replace” dialog box with format change]

---

Note: All screenshots are from Microsoft Word 2013. 
Text screenshots (“The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.”)
are using Calibri (Body) font, 11 pt., at a zoom level of 130%.